# Replace random E mail provider to one

Tags: notepad++

> ballmaus@msn.de:schatzreyen
>
> theaerox@yahoo.de:Wellness
>
> autocrasher@web.de:computer

need

> ballmaus@gmail.com:schatzreyen
>
> theaerox@gmail.com:Wellness
>
> autocrasher@gmail.com:computer

what regex work to do that?

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? Regex for email (at least a basic one) should be easy to google, then modify it to fit your problem

Answer (score 1):

We need to replace everything between `@` and the first `:` with `gmail.com`.

Remembering to set `Search Mode` to `Regular expression`, we can do the following:

```
Find what: @[^:]*:

Replace with: @gmail.com:
```